# What is difference between getHeight() and getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels

Tags: android, android-view

I have a class extends View.
In this class, i use getHeight() and it returns 924
But when i use getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels, it returns 960.
I dont know why. Someone can explain for me? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

`getHeight()` gives you the height of a particular `View`

`getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels` gives you the height of your screen (this includes things like status bar which usually will not be included in your `View's` height even if it has `match_parent` for `layout_height`)

[image]

Comment: @NguyễnĐạt feel free to accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: @NguyễnĐạt, if you find this answers your question - please mark it as the correct one.